# What difference is there beween the Windows Azure staging and production areas?

Tags: deployment, azure, production

I ask because I had an app working perfectly in staging, but now that it is in production, fiddler tells me the response is a 502 error when I request the page in a browser. Has anyone any idea what might cause this? I could simply leave it in staging, its academic work so its not a big deal, but it is annoying though. Iv waited at least 30 mins and still the same result so I doubt if it is going to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there's no difference except DNS addressing - and you should be able to swap Staging and Production rather than uploading straight to Production.

Answer (score 0):

One big difference for me is that the staging has a random guid as part of the domain so I can't easily reference in my testing.  I also can't easily set it as a target for my web deployments.

So, when I'm in dev mode, I tend to just have two separate web role projects that are both non-guid names and use one as staging and one as relatively stable production for other team members.

That said, for real production, I do use staging because I can test the VIP swap which is a much better way to go live than waiting 20 minutes to see if it worked. (and what if it did not)?

My 2cents.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved, I guess I had to wait 32 minutes. GAE FTW

Comment: that's odd. I can run the staging version of my app right away after deployment.